# What is the explanation of this error 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Not Found [404]' while uploading a BLOB?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

**Is there an explanation for the error below?**

I'm calling `UploadObjectAsync()`([from this library](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/3.4.0/index.html)), and then this exception occurs:

```
ERROR: The service storage has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Not Found [404]
Errors [
    Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]

at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.CheckFinalProgress()
at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Storage.GoogleCloudStorage.UploadToStorageAsync(Byte[] fileBytes, String currentYear, String submissionGuid, String fileName, String bucketName, String contentType)
```

I checked [the Cloud Storage HTTP response code docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#404_Not_Found), but that didn't bear any fruit.

I'm calling the overload below of the method in question:

```
public virtual Task<Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object> UploadObjectAsync(string bucket, string objectName, string contentType, Stream source, UploadObjectOptions options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, IProgress<IUploadProgress> progress = null);
```

I also tried uploading an empty byte array (as opposed to the non-empty byte array I was using when I first encountered the error), but it results in the same error.

[Nuget package in question](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/3.2.0?_src=template)

Comment: In azure blob must be in container. I do not know how it is in Google

Comment: Show the code, the endpoint and the stacktrace + message in your question.

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you encounter this error while uploading a BLOB, it probably means that the bucket being targeted doesn't exist.

In retrospect, this should have been obvious, but I changed the bucket name and forgot that buckets have to be explicitly created.